# Get autocomplete address list of Outlook in VBA

Tags: vba, autocomplete, outlook

I am trying to add all my "autocompleted addresses" to a new contact folder but I can't get those addresses. What I call "autocompleted addresses" are the addresses saved when you send an email to somebody and you type it again in the "To" field of a new email.

I know I can get all the Global Address List by using

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")    
Set GAL = myNameSpace.AddressLists("Offline Global Address List")
```

But how can I get my autocompleted addresses ?

I am using Outlook 2010 and my account is an Exchange Account.

Thank you for your help and your time.

**EDIT**

My complete code :

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set folder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
Set storage = folder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass)
Set propacc = storage.PropertyAccessor
Set got = propacc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102")
```

Problem : got is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete (nickname) stream is stored in a hidden (associated) message with the message class of `"IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete"` in the Inbox folder. Its format is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625288.aspx. You can access that message using `MAPIFolder.GetStorage`.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes nicknames through the `RDOStore` / `RDOSession`.[Nicknames](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdonicknames.htm) collection.

Also note that in case of Outlook VBA you do need to create an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object, you already have an intrinsic Application variable pointing to that object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly, I cannot use Redemption Library. Is there a way to extract the nicknames with the storage object?

Comment: Yes, you will need to parse the data stored in the 0x7C090102 property on that hidden message.

Comment: Okay, I tried 
`Set propacc = storage.PropertyAccessor`
         and `Set got = propertyAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102")`
But it doesn't seem to work (the variable got is empty). How can I get and parse the data ?

Comment: Ok, now you have to parse it.

Comment: Can you see that property in OutlookSpy (click IMAPIFolder, go to the "Associated Contents" tab)?

Comment: I installed OutlookSpy (great work btw), I went in the "Associated Contents", no "0x7C090102" entry... What does it mean?

Comment: You need to open (double click) the message with PR_MESSAGE_CLASS = "IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete"

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. It's okay, I can see the nickname. How can I get it in my VBA and parse it?

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the right hidden message? Please post the relevant snippet of your code.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
Set got = propertyAcc.GetProperty(yadayada)
```

Don't use Set... just

```
got = propertyAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102")
```

This will give a zero-based array of the bytes used in the text stream.
got(0) = 13
got(1) = 240
etc etc...

From there, you can analyze each byte to get the text... but it would be very very ugly to parse it all out, when Redemption does that for you.  In fact, if you've gotten this far in the post, then you've probably sorted out that it would be a better use of time to figure out how to use Redemption than to build your own parser for this purpose.