# How can I read in the cache entries from outlook and then save them as contacts in my address book?

Tags: c#, caching, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am currently programming an Outlook Add-in with C# in Visual Studio. Now I would like to read in existing entries of the cache in order to automatically save the contacts contained therein as an entry in my address book. Can anyone help me further on how I can access the cache and then implement my function?

So far I already did following steps:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
...
private Outlook.Application OutlookApplication;
private MAPIFolder inboxFolder;
...
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
...
 inboxFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
...
}

private void saveContact()
{
StorageItem storage = inboxFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByEntryID);
PropertyAccessor propertyAcc = storage.PropertyAccessor;
byte[] got = propertyAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102");
}
```

I am currently calling the method for testing when opening an inspector.

So far I get the following error message:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "The StorageItem item cannot be created in this folder. Either the folder is read-only, or storage items are not allowed in this folder. "

Can somebody help me fix my error?

Comment: Which cache entries? Do you mean the autocomplete list?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes exactly

Comment: Use `olIdentifyByMessageClass` instead of `olIdentifyByEntryID`

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete (nickname) cache stream is stored in a hidden message with the message class of `IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete` in the Inbox folder (see the associated content of the folder). The format is documented, see [Nickname cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/nickname-cache?redirectedfrom=MSDN). You can access that message using `MAPIFolder.GetStorage` and then you can get the stream itself:

```
Set propAcc = storage.PropertyAccessor
Set got = propertyAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102")
```

You may find the [Get autocomplete address list of Outlook in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516429/get-autocomplete-address-list-of-outlook-in-vba) thread helpful.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer.
I have now inserted the code into the ThisAddIn class and get the following error message:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "The StorageItem item cannot be created in this folder. Either the folder is read-only, or storage items are not allowed in this folder. "
Have I inserted the code correctly, or how can I fix the exception?

Comment: What is your code? Have you tried using any tool for exploring hidden internals like MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy?

Comment: I have expanded my original question to include the code. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete stream is stored as a hidden (associated) message with the message class of `"IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete"` in the Inbox folder. You can see the data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author): go to the Inbox folder, click IMAPIFolder button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the "Associated Contents" tab, locate a message with PR_MESSAGE_CLASS == "IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", select the `PR_ROAMING_BINARYSTREAM` property to see its contents.

You can open that message using the Outlook Object Model (`MAPIFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass`), read the property using `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`, then parse it. Note that large (>30kB) autocomplete streams cannot be opened using `PropertyAccessor`.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) an option (I am also its author), it exposes autocomplete as the [RDONicknames](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdonicknames.htm) collection:

```
 set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
 Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
 set Nicknames = Session.GetNicknames
 for each NickName in NickNames
     Debug.Print NickName.Name & " - " & NickName.SmtpAddress
 next
```

Comment: So first of all: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I always get following error message: ```System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "The StorageItem item cannot be created in this folder. Either the folder is read-only or storage items are not allowed in this folder. " ``` When I open the message using Outlook Object Model ```MAPIFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass)``` What is my mistake?

Comment: What kind of store is it? IMAP4? Can you see that hidden message in OutlookSpy (click IMAPIFolder, go to the "Associated Contents" tab)?